# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Pow: 'list' and 'int' on line 15

Tags: python, typeerror

All I want to do is have my loop use the distance formula to move the turtle down every second. However, every time I try and use the formula this error comes up. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
tony = turtle.Turtle()
tony.shape("turtle")
tony.pensize(5)
tony.up()
tony.left(90)
tony.forward(100)
tony.left(180)
tony.down()

gravity= float(10.3)

for i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]:
    tony.stamp()
    time = range(1,10,1)
    distance = float((gravity/2)*((time**2)-((time-1)**2)))
    tony.forward(distance)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range` function returns a list. You are storing this list in `time`, and then attempting to use it as the base of `time ** 2` (time squared). Perhaps you wanted to set time to the value of `i`?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `time = range(1, 10, 1)` is equivalent to `time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and so trying to square a list, as in `distance = float((gravity/2)*((time**2)-((time-1)**2)))` is undefined.

If your intention was to square each element in the list (i.e. `[1, 4, 9, 16, ...]` then what you're trying to do is formally called a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(mathematics)). Fortunately, python has a [builtin map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map).

```
f = lambda x: x**2
map(f, list)
```

Above I used a lambda, which is an inline function. you could just have (slightly less) easily (slightly more inline with PEP8):

```
def f(x):
    return x ** 2

map(f, list)
```

**Also:**
You subtracted 1 from your list as well. I'll leave it up to you to figure out a solution to that using the tools above.